# data partitioning by criterion in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I split the data by the criterion?

```
SELECT [Dt]
      , [CustomerName]

      , [ItemRelation]

      , [SaleCount]
      , [DocumentNum]
      , [DocumentYear]
      , [IsPromo]
      , [CustomerType]
  FROM [Action]. [Dbo]. [FC]
```

[IsPromo] has the values ​​0 and 1.
I need to divide the data by the number of sales by [SaleCount] for the zero category ispromo!

For example, i have 20 observations by ispromo = 0, where [SaleCount] is only 15 not zero values.
Calculate the coefficient, divide the total number of days by the number of days where there were no zero sales by salecount.
15/20 = 0.75.
It must be done for each strata (groups) [CustomerName] + [ItemRelation] + [DocumentYear] separately.
So, if within group such  coefficient is greater than 0.71, then such groups should be written into a table
mytab1
if less, then in mytab2

How to do it?

data sample

```
Dt  CustomerName    ItemRelation    SaleCount   DocumentNum DocumentYear    IsPromo
2018-02-19 00:00:00.000 1   11683   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-20 00:00:00.000 1   11683   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-21 00:00:00.000 1   11683   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-22 00:00:00.000 1   11683   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-23 00:00:00.000 1   11683   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-24 00:00:00.000 1   11683   1339    999 2018    0
2018-02-25 00:00:00.000 1   11683   81  999 2018    0
2018-02-26 00:00:00.000 1   11683   487 999 2018    0
2018-02-27 00:00:00.000 1   11683   861 999 2018    0
2018-02-28 00:00:00.000 1   11683   546 999 2018    0
2018-03-01 00:00:00.000 1   11683   722 999 2018    0
2018-03-02 00:00:00.000 1   11683   890 999 2018    0
2018-03-03 00:00:00.000 1   11683   1128    999 2018    0
2018-03-04 00:00:00.000 1   11683   81  999 2018    0
2018-03-05 00:00:00.000 1   11683   884 999 2018    0
2018-03-06 00:00:00.000 1   11683   3675    999 2018    0
2018-03-07 00:00:00.000 1   11683   3780    999 2018    0
2018-03-08 00:00:00.000 1   11683   3178    999 2018    0
2018-03-09 00:00:00.000 1   11683   1749    999 2018    0
2018-03-10 00:00:00.000 1   11683   1243    999 2018    0
```

this stratum has coef=0,75
it goes to mytab1

and this stratum

```
Dt  CustomerName    ItemRelation    SaleCount   DocumentNum DocumentYear    IsPromo
2018-02-19 00:00:00.000 2   11684   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-20 00:00:00.000 2   11684   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-21 00:00:00.000 2   11684   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-22 00:00:00.000 2   11684   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-23 00:00:00.000 2   11684   0   999 2018    0
2018-02-24 00:00:00.000 2   11684   1339    999 2018    0
2018-02-25 00:00:00.000 2   11684   81  999 2018    0
2018-02-26 00:00:00.000 2   11684   487 999 2018    0
2018-02-27 00:00:00.000 2   11684   861 999 2018    0
2018-02-28 00:00:00.000 2   11684   546 999 2018    0
2018-03-01 00:00:00.000 2   11684   722 999 2018    0
```

has coef 0,545454545
11 days by zero category of ispromo
and 6 day was with non zero obs by salescount.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and your desired results. It's hard to parse the text description/example. I suspect a [Window Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would do the job here

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @JNevill edited post, please check

Answer (score 2):

A simple method uses `avg()` with `group by`:

```
select CustomerName, ItemRelation, DocumentYear,
       avg( case when IsPromo > 0 then 1.0 end) as promo_ratio
from action.dbo.fc
group by CustomerName, ItemRelation, DocumentYear;
```

You can then use `having avg( case when IsPromo > 0 then 1.0 end) > 0.71` for your filtering.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, i edited post. is your code works with sample data?

Comment: @vari . . . This returns the `CustomerName`/`ItemRelation`/`DocumentYear` triples that match.  If you want the original rows, you can use `JOIN` or `EXISTS`.